GH Actions: No File Or Directory | Directory Structure
I currently have a GH Actions that sets itself with Packer and Ansible and than call packer build command. The packer has a shell provisioner which executes a shell script but it's not able to call a child shell script.
File Structure:
REPO
├─ .github/workflow
├─ packer
|  ├─ image1/...
|  ├─ image2/...
|  └─ build.sh
└─ scripts
   ├─ runtimes
   |  ├─ node
   |  ├─ java
   |  ├─ docker
   |  └─ install.sh
   └─ ...

GH Workflow:
name: Release AMI

run-name: "Release sc-${{ inputs.release_name }}"

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
     ...

jobs:
  release:
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: 'Run `packer build`'
        run: |
          echo "Debug: GITHUB_WORKSPACE=${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}"
          echo "Debug: PWD=$(pwd)"
          echo "Debug: Directory contents:"
          ls -la

          export PATH="/home/runner/.local/bin:$PATH"
          bash images/build.sh \
            "${{ inputs.aws_cli_version }}" \
            "${{ inputs.codedeploy_version }}" \
            "${{ inputs.ssm_channel }}" \
            "${{ inputs.docker }}" \
            "${{ inputs.node_version }}" \
            "${{ inputs.java_version }}" \
            "${{ github.workspace }}" \
            "${{ github.action }}"


Based on the input provided, the build shellscript generates a packer build command. The build.pkr.hcl has a shell provisioner,
...
  provisioner "shell" {
    script           = "${path.cwd}/scripts/runtimes/install.sh"
    environment_vars = [
      "GITHUB_WORKSPACE=${var.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}",
      "GITHUB_ACTIONS=${var.GITHUB_ACTIONS}"
    ]
    timeout          = "15m"
  }
...

The shell script has following line,
echo "Debug from utils.sh:"
echo "GITHUB_WORKSPACE=${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}"
sudo ls $GITHUB_WORKSPACE

Here the workflow fails saying that tha workspace doesn't exist.
==> amazon-ebs.jammy: ls: cannot access '/home/runner/_work/repo-name/repo-name': No such file or directory

So from my understanding the whole context loop of terminal session is switching from,
GH Action Runner -> build.sh script -> packer -> install.sh script

But there is no change in job so the directory should persist. What am I doing wrong here?

install.sh script is being executed on the aws machine and on that machine the directory /home/runner/_work/repo-name/repo-name does not exist

Damn, completely missed that. Will need to check how can I pass the selected artifacts to EC2. Thanks
